# Creating an intent chooser without launching the selected intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-package-managers

I was trying to create an intent chooser in order to store the user's selected intent for later use, but nothing seems to work.

`Intent.CreateChooser` only seems to work when actually launching the intent, and even then it doesn't return the selected intent back to the calling activity but just launches it.

The only other solution I could come up with, which seems tedious to me, is to generate a list of activities from PackageManager and then create an interface for the user to select the activity from the results:

```
PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
List<ResolveInfo> info = manager.queryIntentActivities(myIntent,PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
```

It technically should work, but since "CreateChooser" already exists, I find it hard to believe that there isn't a way to use it (or a similar system method) to display an activity chooser and parse the result.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [`ACTION_PICK_ACTIVITY`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PICK_ACTIVITY), as it is described as doing what you want.

Comment: Yes, exactly what I needed, thanks! Found a nice example for how to use it right here: http://www.openintents.org/en/node/263